# How to write a function to get the position of the smallest int in a list?

Tags: list, ocaml

The prototype must be:

```
listMinPos(lst)
```

I'm able to write the same using two arguments, (list and index), but am not able to even think how it can be possible using only the list argument.

The following must hold:

1. only 1 argument (the list).
2. no external libraries.
3. function should be recursive (no 'let' inside the function)

Comment: I somewhat disagree with the method of your teacher. Limiting use of constructs that exist and are part of the language's common idioms always feel a little artificial — here less than in technical interviews, but still.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a solution that cheats slightly : I return the position of the smallest element, *but not only*. The value of the smallest element is also returned.

```
let rec min_pos = function
  | [] -> invalid_arg "min_pos"
  | [x] -> (0, x)
  | hd::tl ->
    let p, v = min_pos tl in
    if hd < v then (0, hd) else (p + 1, v)
```

(As Pascal Cuoq noticed, there is still one `let p, v = .. in ..` remaining; it can be replaced by `match .. with p, v -> ..`. See comments).

Another solution that relax your second constraint (no external library) :

```
let rec min_pos = function
  | [] -> invalid_arg "min_pos"
  | [x] -> 0
  | hd::tl ->
    let p = min_pos tl in
    if hd < List.nth tl p then 0 else p + 1
```

It's inefficient but I don't think you can do much better without passing more information.

#### Edit

I didn't understand this was a homework. Is there a policy against giving complete solution to homework questions ?

Anyway, in this case I suppose that the list of restriction you gave is not, as I supposed, a creativity-forcing constraint, and I suppose that you can break them if it gives better solutions.

I therefore propose, using local `let` :

```
let min_pos li =
  let rec min_pos = function
    | [] -> invalid_arg "min_pos"
    | [x] -> (0, x)
    | hd::tl ->
      let p, v = min_pos tl in
      if hd < v then (0, hd) else (p + 1, v)
  in fst (min_pos li)
```

And a tail-recursive version :

```
let min_pos li =
  let rec min_pos mini mpos cur_pos = function
    | [] -> mpos
    | hd::tl ->
      if hd < mini
      then min_pos hd cur_pos (cur_pos + 1) tl
      else min_pos mini mpos (cur_pos + 1) tl
  in match li with
     | [] -> invalid_arg "min_pos"
     | hd::tl -> min_pos hd 0 1 tl
```

Comment: Your first approach still breaks the "only one `let`" constraint. I am starting to wonder if the teacher tried his own exercise. This one seems really tricky with a single `let`. Of course, as I said elsewhere, perhaps it just feels artificial to me...

Comment: thanks, it works, but it uses let. Is there a way to make that implicit?

Comment: @lalli `let x = e1 in e2` can be written `match e1 with x -> e2` or `(fun x -> e2) e1` :) I hope this is not the answer...

Comment: sorry, I didn't bother about that `let`. Pascal's suggestion seems fine : `match min_pos tl with p, v -> ...`.

Comment: @Pascal,gasche: that works and makes me really curious, why did my teacher add this restriction? I thought using let make the statements "sequential" and not "functional" as my teacher wants, but clearly that's not the case.

Comment: @lalli These tricks do not work if you want to define a recursive let (hopefully you will see why later. It has something to do with the type system :). So perhaps he wanted to see only one recursive function...